# Unable to connect to MS SQL server from shinyapps.io From Windows using sqlOdbcDriver

Tags: sql-server, r, shiny-server, rodbc

I am unable to connect to MS SQL server from shinyapps.io From Windows using sqlOdbcDriver. This works perfectly in RStudio while running locally but when I tried to deploy in shiny server. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

Pls find the below code snippet:

```
con <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server;database=<dbname>;server=<server name>;Uid=<uid>; Pwd=<pwd>")
```

Note : I am using Windows to run R.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your SQL instance allow connections from random Internet addresses? Because that's what shinyapps.io is.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Could you pls let me know how i can check that?

Comment: Allow remote connections to this server option already selected. Still its the same issue